# How to make font color as on picture

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, fonts, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

[image: Example of the font]

Make font color beautiful as shown on title of the page. If you have another ideas about the best font color ever, please don't be so shy, just share it. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: *Comic Sans*. This question is off topic here

Comment: i mean, make same color, as shown on title of the page.

Comment: @NikitaGalaganov are you 100% sure that it is not an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the **"Gradient Brush"**.

Head to the properties window, then to the "brush" section and finally to the "gradient brush".

You could check out the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206969%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and also the [developer nokia link](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Brushes_in_Windows_Phone).